# Symfony2 remember me authentication

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I have site with login form on homepage. Login form have `remember_me` feature. I can't figure out how to convert `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`.

I suppose I should use `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\AbstractRememberMeServices` and method `loginSuccess()` or `autoLogin()` but I don't know how…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to convert the user's role to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`?

The documentation page [How to add "Remember Me" Login Functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) should provide you with all of the information you need to get this working.

Comment: You're right – I've changed my authorization to `isGranted('ROLE_USER')` and it works great…